# deleting rows off database

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i have a table that has members and i want it so when i click a button it deletes that member. i'm using codeigniter with my sql

Member Model

```
 function getMembers(){
 $this->db->select('tblMember.strFirstname, tblMember.strLastname');
 $this->db->from('tblMember');
 }
```

Controller

```
public function getAllMembers()
{
    $this->load->model('Member_model');
    $data['members'] = $this->Member_model->getMembers();
    $this->load->view('member_view', $data);
}
```

member_view

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;First Name #</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-text">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach($members as $row):
            $i++;
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->strFirstname . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->strLastname . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='padding-left:10px'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Delete</button></td>";

    </table>
```

i need it so when i click the delete button it deletes the member
i want to know how do i do this explain code would be great

Thanks for the help in advance :D

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: use form, link or use ajax if you dont want to reload page and execute delete query. what do u want??

Comment: i want to know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

first of all in your model you need to fetch member id too

```
$this->db->select('tblMember.id AS id,tblMember.strFirstname, tblMember.strLastname');
```

change tblMember.id to the your unique column name

then in your views add one more  block like this:

```
...
echo "<td>" . $row->strLastname . "</td>";
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('mycontroller/delete_member/'.$row->id); ?>">Delete this member</a></td>
...
```

*remember to change **mycontroller**/delete_member(bold part) in above code as you need

now you need to add a method to your controller:

```
function delete_member($id=NULL) {
    is_numeric($id) OR show_404();// or redirect
    $is_deleted = $this->Member_model->delete_member($id);
    if ($is_deleted) {
        // delete was successful, set a message or redirect or do something here
    } else {
    // deleting failed, set a message or redirect or do something here
    }
}
```

okay, now you need to create a method in your Member_model()

```
function delete_member($id) {
$this->db->delete('tblMember', ['id'=>$id]);
return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

don't forget to change id in ['id'=>$id] to your column name

It's pretty much the same thing you are doing when retrieving a row a show